# load admob is not working in android app

Tags: android, admob

hello im trying to add banner to my app i added unit id and app id in the appropriate way i think.. but the Advertising not load and it place keep empty.
i think the problem is not in the place of banner because its place keep empty and i try to show it in another activity but i get the same result.
i have MainActivity.java in onCreate it contain the following :

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-*****************~**********");

 mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

activity_main.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
       </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-****************/**********">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you checking on a real device or in the emulator?

Comment: On a real device!

Comment: Make sure you set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same manner (i.e. set both in XML or both programmatically).

Comment: try to addTestDevice(" Your DEVICE ID") in adRequest

Comment: I set both in xml!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its working now without change anything in the code, i think it needs several hours to activate